# Draw vertical border line in HTML email using VBA

Tags: html, vba, email

I am using a VBA userform from which a user can send an email.

How do I create a vertical orange line as shown below?
[image]

In HTML, it would be something like this:

```
style="border-left: solid 4px #FF6801;">
```

Edit: answer based on Tim's answer:

```
Dim ol As Outlook.Application, m As Outlook.MailItem

Set ol = New Outlook.Application
        
Set m = ol.CreateItem(olMailItem)
m.Display
m.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
        
m.HTMLBody = "<p style='border-left: solid 4px #FF6801;padding: 24px;margin-left:24px;'>" & VariableName.Value & "</p>"
```

Comment: You should post your code to give you an answer. But generally you can set the body of the email as HTML or plain text. Try a simple tag like the bold `<b> test </b>` if it doesn't work that's probably the problem. [Check this link, the property should be `.bodyformat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.bodyformat)

Comment: Best first step in getting help is to post the relevant parts of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```vb
Dim ol As Outlook.Application, m As Outlook.MailItem

Set ol = New Outlook.Application
        
Set m = ol.CreateItem(olMailItem)
m.Display
m.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
        
m.HTMLBody = "<p>No border</p>" & _
             "<p style='border-left: solid 4px #FF6801;'>With border</p>" & _
             "<p>No border</p>"
```

Comment: Thanks Tim! Works well, however, what if I would like to add a little margin of let's say 24px from the line to the next (as shown in screenshot)?

Comment: Edit: next = text

Comment: Got it working by adding both a margin and a padding! I will update the original post